# Possible to add a read more link in an RSS Feed?

Tags: wordpress, rss

This may be a weird or stupid question, but I have the following code (http://pastebin.com/PTFtqkvs) and I want to place a simple "read more" link after the description which links to the the article in the rSS feed - however whatever I do isn't working. Is it even possible to add this option and still conform to the rSS guidelines? This is built using a WP system to show Posts in a certain category.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As long as your conforming to the RSS spec, most readers usually make the title a link to the complete article - I can't see a need for a 'read more' link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook onto feed specific hooks to add that to your feed content. Something like this in your theme's functions.php would work:

```
function my_super_awesome_feed_linker( $content ){
  $extra = "<a href='" . get_permalink() . "'>Read More...</a>";
  return $content . $extra;
}

add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'my_super_awesome_feed_linker' );
```

This will add a 'read more' link to all your feeds, though.

In order for this to work, you need to use a normal WordPress loop and the function `the_excerpt_rss()` instead of what you do in your code, `echo $post->post_excerpt;`. I've modified your pastebin here:

http://pastebin.com/6Y8pewhW

Also, just a word of advice, this won't really work as a template. WordPress has already sent headers by the time you've gotten to the page's template file. So you'll need to find a way to get those headers sent correctly, or to override them. The two easiest ways would be to filter the header content or to query the posts at `'wp_loaded'` before headers are sent.

Comment: this code doesn't work, it doesn't even display the rss feed contents (http://dev.liquor.com/custom-rss-feed/)

Comment: Because, as I warned you in the end of my answer, WordPress is setting the header to html, not xml. My solution works if you're properly implementing the feed in the first place.